# Power analysis to predict % increase in performance

Tags: python, r, matlab, statistics

I am performing a binary classification using SVM and 10 features between two groups : 45 healthy vs 15 non-healthy and it gives me an auc of 0.80. Is there a way to perform a power analysis  to estimate how many subjects we need from each group to increase the overall AUC by 5%? Or in other words, is there a way to obtain a curve of % increase in AUC vs no. of samples?

I looked at the sampsizepwr function in matlab but i do not think this will give the plot i  need:

nout = sampsizepwr(testtype,p0,p1)

Can someone please guide me here? I can also try in R or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUC in principle shouldn't change by N size. However, with larger N you will be more certain that the AUC for your sample of subjects is similar to the general population. Here I simulate a random sampling of "subjects", 15 sick and 45 healthy, then compute AUC. I do it 30 times and get AUC between 0.69 to 0.93. I multiply the sample size by 100 and AUC range is 0.8 to 0.82.

```
n = [45,15];
rng(3)
for mult = 1:100
    for iter = 1:30
        healthy = normrnd(0,1,n(1)*mult,1);
        abnormal = normrnd(1.25,1,n(2)*mult,1);
        score = [healthy;abnormal];
        label = [zeros(n(1)*mult,1);ones(n(2)*mult,1)];
        [~,~,~,AUC(mult,iter)] = perfcurve(label,score,1);
    end
end
M = mean(AUC,2);
SD = std(AUC,[],2);
figure;
errorbar(M',SD')
xlabel('How many times to multiply N subjects')
ylabel('Mean AUC for 30 iterations (bars = SD)')
title('AUC by N subjects')
ylim([0.5 1])
box off
grid on
```

[image: AUC by N]